Repeated pop up on mobile phone
I see this is popping up repeatedly, how to stop this? , It's very irritating.


This question is lacking useful information like 1. What did you do that causes the pop up 2. Since how long does it happen 3. Android version and device details. Include these and any other details that describe the problem by [edit]inge the question and selecting suitable tags //Besides, does it happen in [tag:safe-mode]?,. If it doesn't, it means some installed app is causing this

That popup looks like the one you get by longer touching text e.g. on a web site or in an app. Just do a short touch somewhere outside of the popup to close it.

Welcome. This question was migrated to Android.SE (for the correct reason). However, as of the current writing, it lacks details (as per comments) and might get closed (which will be migrated back and closed on the source site). Consider [edit]ing the question and addressing the comments. Thanks.
